# How to base64 encode image bytes in IE8

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, internet-explorer-8, base64

We need to base64 encode image element data using javascript in IE8 without 32 KB limit. Is there any way to achieve this?

We tried using canvas workaround

```
function getImageData(_id)
{
    var c = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById(_id);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL();
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

but unofortunately IE8 doesn't support canvas either. Tried to include [ExploreCanvas](https://github.com/arv/ExplorerCanvas) with no success.

Is there any other workaround to base64 encode arbitrary size image in IE8?

Comment: do you need to encode (as in the title of the question) or `extract base64 encoded` (or, as some may say it, decode)?

Comment: I meant encode the image. Updated the description

Comment: what is `the 32 KB limit` - what is limited to 32 KB?

Comment: The data uri is limited to 32 KB afaik

Comment: there's no way around that

Comment: I felt so close until I realize that IE8 doesn't support `xhr.overrideMimeType()`, nor the loading of binary data through xhr...

Comment: I think the only solution would be to send your image with a text/plain header, so that IE8 would be able to load your image's content. Then you'll be able to encode it to base64 on front-side. But then, it would be better to do the encoding directly server side ;-)